# Cheap, compact 3.7VDC -> 400kVDC (continuous) converters

Tags: power-supply, amplifier, high-voltage

I recently bought some inexpensive and compact (about the size of a 18560 battery) 3.7VDC -> 400kVDC converters. I can confirm they work, and based on the breakdown voltage of air, estimate the output voltage to be in the region of 400kV. Output is continuous and not pulsed.

In principle I guess it would probably be built around the following stages:

1. DC to AC inverter

   Step up AC with a number of transformers in series

   Rectify AC to DC

Unfortunately the circuit is all epoxied up so I can not learn how they did it. My questions are as follows:

1. Do you think the steps I mentioned above are correct?

   Did they use a cascade of transformers for voltage multiplication because of the continuous output?

   I would be grateful for even a rough pseudo circuit schematic to help me understand what is going on.

Comment: Big clive discusses the working of these devices in one of his you-tube videos, search `Big Clive Taser`

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is DC to AC conversion. Most probably they are just stepping up the voltage step by step like in the classic [Cockroft-Walton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockcroft%E2%80%93Walton_generator) circuit. A clock is needed for that, but i would not consider it as AC conversion. A step-up or boost converter could be used as well, where the idea is that if we charge up an inductor and switch off its output load (= generating an open-circuit), than its output voltage could be in theory infinitely high, since the current of the inductor can not flow anywhere. In reality there are always leakage paths and a voltage limit where the some isolating material (even air) breaks through. Such a configuration is seen in this [tear-down video](https://youtu.be/_Zs8nox4QoA?t=463).

There was a small series about charge pumps in the IEEE's SSC Magazine and also an overview in Circuit and Systems Magaizin. They are really good reads. Check it out if you have access to it. (Universities and libraries usually have)

T. Tanzawa, “Innovation of Switched-Capacitor Voltage Multiplier: Part 1: A Brief History,” IEEE Solid-State Circuits Magazine, vol. 8, no. 1, pp. 51–59, winter 2016, doi: 10.1109/MSSC.2015.2495678.

G. Palumbo and D. Pappalardo, “Charge pump circuits: An overview on design strategies and topologies,” IEEE Circuits Syst. Mag., vol. 10, no. 1, pp. 31–45, 2010, doi: 10.1109/MCAS.2009.935695.

About the step up or boost converter, just google it. There are many explanations.